# Using CONCAT() AS column_name to WHERE clause

Tags: mysql, alias

P.S, I'm sorry if my English is bad.
P.P.S, please mark if this question is duplicate.

I have a MySQL query here where I can use the `AS` clause in order to find the specific name. Here's my code below:

```
SELECT CONCAT(students.FirstName, ' ', students.LastName) AS FullName 
FROM `students` WHERE FullName LIKE '%john%'
```

Buy MySQL returned like this:

> #1054 - Unknown column 'FullName' in 'where clause'

How can I achieve this one in order for `FullName` to find what they want?

Comment: Did you try changing the where clause to `WHERE CONCAT(students.FirstName, ' ', students.LastName) LIKE '%john%'` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Fullname` is an alias that you just gave to your "column". It does not exist in DB. If you want to search by "full name" in `WHERE`, you need to repeat the exercise there

```
WHERE CONCAT(students.FirstName, ' ', students.LastName) LIKE '%john%'
```

Optionally, you can pre-built inline view and then `fullname` will become a thing

```sql
SELECT * 
FROM
(
    SELECT
        CONCAT(students.FirstName, ' ', students.LastName) AS FullName
    FROM
        `students`
) inlineView
WHERE 
    FullName LIKE '%joe%'
```

Comment: Is this applicable in Laravel 7? How will I do it in Laravel?